# Out of memory error even after compressing the image

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

Here is my code please check and resolve my problem .
In this i m getting image through image path i.e. i'm taking that in `selectimage1`, `selectimage2`...goes on and after that i have taken the image in Bitmap and then decode and reduce its size den also getting out of memory error .

so please help me to get out of it.

thanks

```
    location=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    category=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.category);
    subcategory=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.subcategory);
    title=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    description=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
    phonenumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
    email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    price=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.price);
    postadd=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_post);


    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    locationname = preferences.getString("Location", "Location");

    SharedPreferences preferences1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    categoryname = preferences1.getString("categoryname", "categoryname");

    SharedPreferences imagepath1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath1 = imagepath1.getString("picturePath1", "picturePath1");


    SharedPreferences imagepath2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath2 = imagepath2.getString("picturePath2", "picturePath2");

    SharedPreferences imagepath3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath3 = imagepath3.getString("picturePath3", "picturePath3");

    SharedPreferences imagepath4 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath4 = imagepath4.getString("picturePath4", "picturePath4");


    Bitmap thumbnail1 = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath1));
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, stream);

    Bitmap thumbnail2 = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath2));
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, stream1);

    Bitmap thumbnail3 = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath3));
    int size3 = 10;
    Bitmap bitmapsimplesize3 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail3 ,thumbnail3.getWidth() / size3, thumbnail3.getHeight() / size3, true);

    Bitmap thumbnail4 = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath4));
    int size4 = 10;
    Bitmap bitmapsimplesize4 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail4 ,thumbnail4.getWidth() / size4, thumbnail4.getHeight() / size4, true);

    imageview1.setImageBitmap(thumbnail1);
    imageview2.setImageBitmap(thumbnail2);
    imageview3.setImageBitmap(bitmapsimplesize3);
    imageview4.setImageBitmap(bitmapsimplesize4);

    location.setText(locationname);
    category.setText(categoryname);
    subcategory.setText(subcategoryname);
    subcategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this line to your manifest file....It will allocate the large memory for your application..

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try That:

```
imageview1.setImageBitmap(null);
imageview2.setImageBitmap(null);
imageview3.setImageBitmap(null);
imageview4.setImageBitmap(null);
imageview1.setImageBitmap(thumbnail1);
imageview2.setImageBitmap(thumbnail2);
imageview3.setImageBitmap(bitmapsimplesize3);
imageview4.setImageBitmap(bitmapsimplesize4);
```

and also `finish();` previous unusable activities.

Or

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: instead of shared preference what other i can use because in shared preference it holds the last image

Answer (score 0):

Try scaling down the Bitmap instead of compressing it. The official Android website has a very detailed guide for this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/